# Append html and keep indentation

Tags: php, jquery

I need to append an html string (that is a reply) using jQuery from a php call inside an iframe, but I need also to keep the indentation.
Basically I send a reply to php that elaburates it and send it back through jquery that will post it, however I need to keep the markup(tabs,spaces,etc), is there a way to do it? At this moment I use this:

```
echo "<script>parent.$('#formreply').nimbleLoader('hide');parent.post_reply('".addslashes($_POST['message'])."','".$date."','".htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['name'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8')."',".$json.");</script>";
```

But I need to remove every markeup with `trim(preg_replace('/\s+/','',$_POST['message']))`, otherwise js returns: `unterminated string literal`.
This is an example of a post(the `eco`):

```
parent.$('#formreply').nimbleLoader('hide');parent.post_reply('<pre class=\"html\">
&lt;script&gt;
alert(\'ciao\')
alert(\'ciao\')
&lt;/script&gt;</pre>
<p> </p>','2013-11-01 12:29:58','Admin',null);
```

**EDIT**

```
function post_reply(mess, dat, name, up) {
        totalmsg++;
        <?php if(!$isMob){ ?> 
            CKEDITOR.instances.message.setData(''); 
        <?php } else { ?> 
            editor.setValue("", true); 
        <?php } ?> 
        $(".uploadfilebox").each(function () {
            $(this).remove()
        });
        $(".attlist").append("<div class='row-fluid uploadfilebox'></div>");
        tail = [];
        $("#messages").children(".row-fluid:first").hasClass("oddmessage") ? tail.push('<div class="row-fluid evenmessage" style="display:none"><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span2 usrinfo"><p class="username">' + name + '</p><p class="date">' + dat + '</p><p class="postnumber">Post Number: '+totalmsg+'</p></div><div class="span8 messagecell">' + mess + "</div></div>") : tail.push('<div class="row-fluid oddmessage" style="display:none"><div class="row-fluid"><div class="span2 usrinfo"><p class="username">' + name + '</p><p class="date">' + dat + '</p><p class="postnumber">Post Number: '+totalmsg+'</p></div><div class="span8 messagecell">' + mess + "</div></div>");
        if (null != up){
            tail.push('<div class="row attachment"><div class="span2 offset1 attachmentsec">Attachment</div><div class="span8">');
            var count= up.length;
            for (i=0; i < count; i++) 
                tail.push("<form class='download_form' method='POST' action='../php/function.php' target='hidden_upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input type='hidden' name='ticket_id' value='" + up[i][0] + "'/><input type='hidden' name='file_download' value='" + up[i][1] + "'/><input type='submit' class='btn btn-link download' value='" + up[i][2] + "'> &nbsp;&nbsp; <i class='icon-remove-sign remfile' title='Delete File' alt='Delete File'></i></form>");
            tail.push("</div></div>");
        }
        tail.push("</div>");
        $(".newest").remove();
        $("#messages").children(".row-fluid:first").before(tail.join(""));
        $("#messages").children(".row-fluid:first").delay(300).show('scale');
        $('#fielduploadinput').wrap('<form>').closest('form').get(0).reset();
        $('#fielduploadinput').unwrap();
        add++;
        writing=false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried sending a JSON encoded HTML string rather than raw HTML and then converting it to HTML when it's received?

Comment: @popnoodles I haven't thought about it, how can I reconvert it to a valid HTML with js?

Comment: You only need to parse the whole HTML and JS as one string and decode it `html_and_js = $.parseJSON(the_json_encoded_html_and_js);`

Comment: ...because function post_reply() is not shown in the question I can't post an answer.

Comment: @popnoodles I have just tried to append it "as it is", so the json encoded string and it works, is it "safe" (browser behaviour)?

Comment: Sending html from one function to another doesn't, as far as I know, cause safety issues. If I wanted to insert HTML on your page I wouldn't be looking at your functions to do it, I'd just insert it where I want. With regards to the data being POSTed, I would expect the server to be validating the request, so yes it's safe.